# How to Automatically Get Weights from Parented Object to Vertex Groups?

Tags: scripting, rigging, groups

[image]

Is there a Script that makes vertex groups and then rigs the object that you selected to it? 
I know about the Automatic Weights, But it doesn't work the Right way I needed too.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the reasons why weighting with automatic weights does not meet your needs?

Comment: It does It to every single bone. I just want it to do it to the bone I selected.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to indicate that the weighting is only done from selected bones. What you can do is removing the 'deform' option from the other bones, though.